# Adding columns you created in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

So say I have a mysql statement like this:

```
  SELECT username, @n := @n + 1 ranking, `1st places`, `2nd places`, `3rd places`, `top5`, `top3
FROM
(
SELECT username,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `1st places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `2nd places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `3rd places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating < 6 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `top5`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating < 4 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `top3`
FROM Table1
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY `1st places` DESC
) q, (SELECT @n := 0) n
```

How can I add up the columns that I created called, '1st places' + '2nd places' + '3rd places' in this sql statement and create another column called "total finishes"? Seems easy, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: I don't quite get it. `rating < 4` overlaps with `rating = 1` and so does partially with `rating < 6`. Can you give some example data with expected output so see what you want to do?

Comment: so what I want is a point system. Example: say someone places 1st aka "rating=1" then they get a point for being in 1st, then they also get 5 points for being in the top 5 (aka rating < 6) and also get 5 more points for being in the top 3 (aka rating < 4) so they would get a total of 11 points.

Comment: Im realizing how dumb this is actually now that I typed all of that, but I guess is there a way to do that? Even tho thinking about it, I dont need it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add them together and give an alias to that extra column:-

```
SELECT username, @n := @n + 1 ranking, `1st places`, `2nd places`, `3rd places`, `top5`, `top3, `1st places` + `2nd places` + `3rd places` AS `total finishes`
FROM
(
SELECT username,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `1st places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `2nd places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `3rd places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating < 6 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `top5`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating < 4 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `top3`
FROM Table1
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY `1st places` DESC
) q, (SELECT @n := 0) n
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't re-use a field with a calculated value in the same `SELECT` query, however wrapping into an additional sub-query may be an option:

```
SELECT username, @n := @n + 1 ranking, `1st places`, `2nd places`, `3rd places`, `top5`, `top3
FROM
(
    SELECT
    *,
    `1st places`+`2nd places`+`3rd places` `total finishes`
    FROM (
        SELECT username,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `1st places`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `2nd places`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `3rd places`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rating < 6 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `top5`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rating < 4 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `top3`
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY username
        ORDER BY `1st places` DESC
    )
)
q, (SELECT @n := 0) n
```

Haven't tried, still...